# PHP - Using Sqlite3 and min() function

Tags: php, html, sqlite

I'm using PHP to pull out information from an SQLite3 database.

All the basic queries work until I start trying to do something clever by using the min() aggregate function.

This works in interactive SQLite3:

```
select distinct car, colour, min(time) from car_table group by car;
```

But when in PHP:

```
$db = new SQLite3('carDB.db');
$car_query= $db->query('select distinct car, colour, min(time) from car_table group by car');

while($row=$car_query->fetchArray()){
  echo "Car :" . $row["car"];
  echo "Colour :" . $row["colour"];
  echo "Time :" . $row["time"];
}
```

This doesn't print out `time`, a check to see if the key `time` exists in the array returns negative.

If I simply have `time` in the query rather than `min(time)` it prints out fine.

I'm using `count(*)` in another PHP block which works fine, which ruled out aggregate functions not being supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key in your results array will be `min(time)` as no alias has been provided.

If you want the key to be `time` you'll need to alias the column in your query like so:

```
min(time) as time
```